# SwiperJS library not working properly: Swiper is not defined

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

So I'm trying to use the SwiperJS library, but it doesn't work. It's a pretty big website with A LOT of content on the page I'm trying to use it for. The strange thing is, on a small testing website of myself it does work. But when I try to use it on the bigger website console throws an error.

My code:

```
<div class="swiper mySwiper">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-1.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-2.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-3.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-4.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-5.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-6.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>
```

And the JS:

```
<!-- Swiper JS -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js" id="script-swiper"></script>

<!-- Initialize Swiper -->
    <script>
      var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
        pagination: {
        el: ".swiper-pagination",
        },
        observer: true,
        observeParents: true
    });
</script>
```

Console error: `Swiper is not defined at www.url.com/script.js`

I already tried window.onload and to set a timeout of a few seconds before running new Swiper. Does anybody maybe know how to fix this?

Comment: it works for me : https://jsfiddle.net/5ba24kuc/

Comment: are you sure you are not putting also the `<script>` tags inside `script.js`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add CSS tag also in your header:

```
<head><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.css"/></head>
```

p.s. I know it's a year later but hopefully this helps someone who comes across this question.